# How decode binary string react native

Tags: react-native

how could I convert a string in binary to string again in react native?

Ex: 01010 to Hello

I have the code to convert string to binary

Ex: `text.split('').map(l => l.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).join(' '),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let txt="Hello".split('').map(l => l.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).join(' ')
       
let s = txt.split(" ").map(w=> String.fromCharCode(parseInt(w,2)))

console.log(s.join(""))
```

Just convert binary string back to integer and map those values to character using fromCharCode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert binary string to sting you can use `parseInt` and `String.fromCharCode`

`parseInt` converts strings to number. First argument is string value and the second argument is the base value in which the string representation is.

```js
let num = parseInt(binaryStr, 2);
```

`String.fromCharCode` converts character code to matching string.

```js
let str = String.fromCharCode(65);
```

Complete code with example:

```js
const text =  'Hello'    
let binaryStr = text.split('').map(l => l.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).join(' ');
console.log('Binary string:', binaryStr);

//To convert binary to string
let strVal = binaryStr.split(' ').map(l => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(l, 2))).join('');
console.log('String:', strVal);
```

**Output of above code:**

Binary string: 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111

String: Hello